# Xamarin Forms NuGet MonoAndroid 7.0

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, nuget

When I browse [Xamarin Forms NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/2.3.4.247), I can see the following dependencies:

**MonoAndroid 1.0**

```
Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (= 23.3.0)
Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.3.0)
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (= 23.3.0)
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView (= 23.3.0)
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter (= 23.3.0)
```

**MonoAndroid 7.0**

```
Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (>= 23.3.0)
Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (>= 23.3.0)
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (>= 23.3.0)
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView (>= 23.3.0)
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter (>= 23.3.0)
```

**WindowsPhone 8.0**

```
WPtoolkit (>= 4.2013.8.16)
```

What is the difference between **MonoAndroid 1.0** and **MonoAndroid 7.0**

Or different way: how can I use MonoAndroid 7.0 in my Xamarin Forms project?

I need to have Xamarin.Android.* **v25.3.1** packages not **v23.3.0**.

MonoAndroid 7.0 seems to be fine with this, but I cannot make it work in Visual Studio.

Comment: Seems no way to do this, why you want to update to v25.3.1 for xamarin forms? Are you trying to use google FCM in XF?